# Error E155010 when setting up Symfony 2.1 using Subversion

Tags: svn, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm using Symfony 2.1.2 and Subversion version 1.7.6 (r1370777).

I'm trying to set up Symfony project using Subversion using the following cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html

But I get error when running command `svn propset svn:ignore "*" app/cache/` and `svn propset svn:ignore "*" app/logs/`. This is the error message:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\symfo-app-21>svn propset svn:ignore "*" app/cache/
'.travis.yml' is not under version controlsvn: E155010: The node 'D:\xampp\htdocs\symfo-app-21\.trav
is.yml' was not found.

D:\xampp\htdocs\symfo-app-21>svn propset svn:ignore "*" app/logs/
'.travis.yml' is not under version controlsvn: E155010: The node 'D:\xampp\htdocs\symfo-app-21\.trav
is.yml' was not found.
```

What could be the problem. Also, I'm going to use NetBeans 7.2 IDE, maybe there are a way to ignore the folder via NetBeans 7.2 that match with command line version on cookbook?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the svn client being stupid.  I've run into the same "proplem" (haha, get it?) on Windows.

The svn client is interpreting asterisk as a wildcard, and is thus substituting every file that matches the wildcard as an argument to the command line.  Thus:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*" app/cache/
```

is being interpreted as thus:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "D:\xampp\htdocs\is.yml" app/cache/
```

And because "D:\xampp\htdocs\is.yml" is not under version control, the command line client throws an error.  This default behavior doesn't make sense, I know.

There are three ways of dealing with this issue.

1. Put the wildcard into a file, and execute propset using the file:

   ```
   echo * > temp-svnignore
   svn propset svn:ignore -F temp-svnignore app/cache/ app/logs/
   del temp-svnignore
   ```
2. Use propedit:

   ```
   set EDITOR=notepad
   svn propedit svn:ignore app/cache/ app/logs/
   ```

Using this method, one editor window will open for each path for which you are setting the property.  In the example above, two editor windows will open, one after the other in the order specified.

1. Specify a wildcard that doesn't match anything in the current directory:

   ```
   svn propset svn:ignore *.php app/cache/
   svn propset svn:ignore *.log app/logs/
   ```